# Count of viewable products in a category

Tags: product, category, collection, product-collection, collection-filtering

Is there any pre-defined way in Magento to get all "viewable" products ?

I want to calculate total count of the products that are viewable in the category page. I know that in each category page, there is a current_category registry that we can use to calculate the number of products in the current category but I want a way to do it for all categories and store the results in a table for each category in each website-store.

The getProductCount not giving the exact number of viewable-only products also simple getProductCollection or similar functions don't return correct results.

Of course viewable products should be enabled, visible, In stock and with qty > 0 and for configurable products there might be at least 1 associated product that have above conditions in the current store view. But there might be stores that show Out of stock products also and label with "Out of Stock".

I want to calculate the exact number shown in category page, how can I do that ? Is there any easy way for this ? Or I need to write complex queries and retrieve data directly from the database?

i.e: I want the exact number calculated here in category page:

[image]

Comment: Why down votes ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use this code

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

It will get you the visible products, since 4 means Catalog and search visibility.
You can combine that with this to add stock check

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
```

Comment: No no, I mean the products that really visible in FE. I wrote an example. i.e A product maybe visible + enable but not in stock, so it won't show in FE.

Comment: You should AVOID by all means querying the DB since 99% of the features you will use to interact with the database are already covered.

Comment: the code you mentioned won't work for all visible+enabled+in stock+qty>0 products. Also consider the example I just wrote about configurable products which are special kind of products. Let me know if there is any pre-defined way of doing this.

Comment: Check my answer again, i just added some code to it.

Comment: Again your edit won't return all products that visible in FE. Tested .

Comment: I've added an image to be more clear. There are lots of situations to be checked. Specially for configurable products. i.e A configurable product maybe enabled, visible and in stock by itself, but non of its associated simple products is enabled. In that case it won't be shown.

Comment: Where do you want to do this? In a phtml or somewhere else?

Comment: No, consider I want to calculate count of all categories active products and store them in a table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mbalparda ... it was a good answer. But can you please revise your answer with the comment I just wrote ? Because the thing I need is a little bit different. Thanks